# Angular directive - isolate scope (&) unable to pass item from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with isolate scope. The directive's template has a ng-repeat on an element. On the same element I have:

```
ng-click="selection(item)"
```

Within the scope of my directive I have:

```
scope: {
    selection: '&'
}
```

The attribute on the directive looks like:

```
selection="onSelection(item)"
```

The controller looks like:

```
$scope.onSelection = function(item) {

}
```

The function is being called but the item is undefined. I'm convinced the item is there because I'm also using ng-class="getClass(item)" again on the same element which is working fine.

Any helpful pointers would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you try ng-click="selection({'item':item})"

Comment: Thanks that worked. I don't know why it's necessary to wrap my domain object in another object, the syntax is somewhat verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Well as it turns out the correct syntax is

`ng-click="selection({'item':item})"`